# McCarthy's Pub Beer Menu

Tags: javascript, html, css

I wrote a little bit of code in JavaScript that takes an array of objects and does some sorting, then outputs to an HTML page. I set a goal to do it without any frameworks, and in functional style on purpose to learn vanilla JS. It would be nice if someone could highlight any bad code or bad practice, and how I could improve it.

This is file with "logic" that I've written:

```js
var coreFunc = function() {
  // Собираем данные из DOM и объекста с товарами
  var placeForBeer = document.getElementById('placeForBeer');
  var placeForAbv = document.getElementById('placeForAbv');
  var filterData = document.getElementById('filters');
  var linksFilter = filterData.querySelectorAll('a');
  var beersArr = listOfAllgoods.beers;

  // Для того, чтобы при загрузке страницы отображались сгрупированный данные для вкладки 'All'. при клике будет будет использоватся отфильстрированная переменная из фунции 'handler' с аналогичны иминем
  var outputArr = beersArr;

  // Генератор шаблона
  var newTemplateGenerator = function(object, sortedArrForAverage) {
    var template = '';
    for (var prop in object) {
      if (object.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
        template += '<h2>' + prop + '</h2>';
        for (var i = 0; i < object[prop].length; i++) {
          template += '<li>' + object[prop][i].name + '<small> (' + object[prop][i].abv + '%) </small>' + '</li>';
        }
      }
    }
    placeForBeer.innerHTML = template;
    placeForAbv.innerHTML = 'Average ABV: ' + getAverageAbv(outputArr) + '%';
  };

  // Функция для переключения вкладок
  var switcher = function(active) {
    for (var i = 0; i < linksFilter.length; i++) {
      linksFilter[i].classList.remove('btn-active');
    }
    active.add('btn-active');
  };



  // Быстрое сложение 2-х чисел
  var add = function(a, b) {
    return a + b;
  };



  var groupByLocale = function(arr) {
    return arr.reduce(function(all, item, index) {
      if (!all[item.locale]) {
        all[item.locale] = [];
      }
      all[item.locale].push(item);
      return all;
    }, {});
  };


  // Выборка из свойств объекта
  var pluck = function(collection, property) {
    return collection.map(function(item) {
      return item[property];
    });
  };

  // Получаем средние арифметическое
  var mean = function(collection, property) {
    if (property) {
      collection = pluck(collection, property);
    }
    return collection.reduce(add) / collection.length;
  };

  // Функция для быстрого округления числа
  var roundDecimal = function(number, round) {
    round = round || 1;
    round = Math.pow(10, round);
    return Math.round(number * round) / round;
  };

  // Рандомный элемент смоделирован для вывода в шаблон
  var randomElement = function(collection) {
    var randomNumber = roundDecimal(Math.random(0, collection.length)) * 10;
    var count = 0;
    var randomItem = collection.filter(function(item) {
      return count++ === randomNumber;
    });
    return randomItem;
  };

  // Используем замыкания для создания готовых фильтров
  var makeFilter = function(collection, property) {
    return function(value) {
      return collection.filter(function(item) {
        return item[property] === value;
      });
    };
  };

  // Присваваем перменной нужный фильтр для удобства
  var filterByLocale = makeFilter(beersArr, 'locale');
  var filterByType = makeFilter(beersArr, 'type');


  // Вызываем функцию для среднего арифметического и обкругляем результат до нужного значения
  var getAverageAbv = function(beers) {
    return roundDecimal(mean(beers, 'abv'));
  };

  // Функция генерации шаблона из нужных даныых

  var start = function() {
    return newTemplateGenerator(groupByLocale(outputArr));
  };


  // 5 Коллбек для filter.addEventListener
  var handler = function(myClick) {
    // Массив из классов элемента по которому нажали
    var ifActive = myClick.target.classList;
    // Парсим текст из атрибута ’data-filter’ для фильтрации
    var dataFilter = myClick.target.getAttribute('data-filter');
    // Запускаем переключаеть кнопок
    switcher(ifActive);

    // Переключатели для вывода нужных данных в зависимости от того, на которую кнопку кликнули
    switch (dataFilter) {
      case 'all':
        outputArr = beersArr;
        break;
      case 'lager':
        outputArr = filterByType('lager');
        break;
      case 'stout':
        outputArr = filterByType('stout');
        break;
      case 'domestic':
        outputArr = filterByLocale('domestic');
        break;
      case 'imports':
        outputArr = filterByLocale('import');
        break;
      case 'ale':
        outputArr = beersArr.filter(function(beer) {
          return beer.type === 'ipa' || beer.type === 'ale';
        });
        break;
      case 'random':
        outputArr = randomElement(beersArr);
        break;
    }

    // Запускаем фильтрацию и вставляем данные в HTML
    start();
  };

  // Запускаем фильтрацию и вставляем данные в HTML
  start();

  // Слушаем событие клик. Второй аргумент это коллбек
  filterData.addEventListener('click', handler);
};

// вызываем основную функцию только когда весь документ загружен
window.onload = coreFunc;

var listOfAllgoods = {
  beers: [{
    "name": "Bitter Hop",
    "type": "ipa",
    "locale": "domestic",
    "abv": 7.7
  }, {
    "name": "Dragonblood Black IPA",
    "type": "ipa",
    "locale": "domestic",
    "abv": 6.9
  }, {
    "name": "Good Dog Lager",
    "type": "lager",
    "locale": "domestic",
    "abv": 5.8
  }, {
    "name": "Good Dog Snowpants",
    "type": "stout",
    "locale": "domestic",
    "abv": 8.1
  }, {
    "name": "Lake Erie 2x IPA",
    "type": "ipa",
    "locale": "domestic",
    "abv": 9.3
  }, {
    "name": "Lake Erie Session",
    "type": "ale",
    "locale": "domestic",
    "abv": 4.1
  }, {
    "name": "Samwell British Pale Ale",
    "type": "ale",
    "locale": "import",
    "abv": 6.5
  }, {
    "name": "Samwell Oatmeal Stout",
    "type": "stout",
    "locale": "import",
    "abv": 5.5
  }, {
    "name": "Samwell Winter Ale",
    "type": "ale",
    "locale": "import",
    "abv": 6.2
  }, {
    "name": "Sparkwood Beer Five",
    "type": "lager",
    "locale": "domestic",
    "abv": 6.5
  }, {
    "name": "Sparkwood Campfire Lager",
    "type": "lager",
    "locale": "domestic",
    "abv": 5.8
  }, {
    "name": "Tartan Scottish Ale",
    "type": "ale",
    "locale": "import",
    "abv": 7.3
  }]
};
```

```css
body {
  background: url("http://i.imgur.com/IDJdOFb.jpg") top left repeat;
  color: white;
}
a:link,
a:hover,
a:active,
a:visited {
  color: #666;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.site-container {
  width: 95%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 550px;
  text-align: center;
}
.fancy {
  font-family: 'Rye', Georga, display, serif;
}
.site-header {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 1em 0;
}
a.header-logo {
  color: red;
  font-size: 3.5em;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
}
#filters {
  line-height: 2.7;
}
#filters a {
  background: #fff;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-family: tahoma;
  font-weight: bold;
}
#filters a.btn-active {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
  border-color: red;
}
#placeForBeer {
  margin: 1em 0;
  padding-left: 0;
}
#placeForBeer li {
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 0;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  line-height: 1.5;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
#placeForBeer li small {
  font-size: 0.75em;
  color: #bbb;
}
#placeForBeer h2 {
  background: rgba(204, 193, 193, 0.5);
  display: block;
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 2em;
  font-variant: small-caps;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Functional JS</title>
  <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Rye' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <link href='style.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <script src="listOfAllBeers.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="site-container">
    <header class="site-header">
      <a href="/" class="header-logo fancy">( McCarthy's Pub )</a>
    </header>
    <h1 class="fancy">Beer List</h1>
    <div id="filters">
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-active" data-filter="all">All</a>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" data-filter="ale">Ales</a>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" data-filter="lager">Lagers</a>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" data-filter="stout">Stouts</a>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" data-filter="random">Suprise</a>
    </div>
    <ul id="placeForBeer"></ul>
    <div id="placeForAbv"></div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Do you want comments on code style and readability or just pure JavaScript feedback?

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things that I think can be improved in here.

In no particular order.

```
querySelectorAll
```

In your code you use

> ```
> filterData.querySelectorAll('a');
> ```

I read this one a few times because and it may just be a style thing. I think writing the following is more expressive:

```
document.querySelectorAll("#filters > a.btn")
```

There are of course other ways to get the same list, the simplest being:

```
filterData.children
```

**`Math.random`**

The signature for Math.random takes no arguments and returns a value from zero to one. [See this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random).

So to pick a random beer from the array of beers you would use:

```
var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * collection.length);
var beer = collection[index];
```

**`newTemplateGenerator`**

I'd like to see this function broken up - it has too many concerns. As you add more concerns to each function you're adding complexity. Simple functions are easier to understand, and reducing the number of things a function is responsible for will make it simpler. The `newTempalteGenerator` function is responsible for:

- Creating the headers
- Creating each beer listing
- Populating the DOM with the generated HTML
- Populating the DOM with the averages

**Switcher function**

You may not need to loop through all links since you already have a reference to the parent object (`filterData`):

```
filterData.querySelectorAll('.btn-active').classList.remove('btn-active')
```

This doesn't protect against the case where there aren't any links on the page, but it should not be possible to get here if that is the case.

**Click handler**

The 'ale' item in the `switch` statement might read nicer as:

```
outputArr = filterByLocale('ipa').concat(filterByLocale('ale'));
```

This uses the `Array.prototype.concat` method which returns an array that contains both lists. And just because I like things to be look pleasing to the eye I prefer:

```
outputArr = [].concat(filterByLocale('ipa')).concat(filterByLocale('ale'));
```

You can also rewrite the switch statement to make use of the default case. This again is down to style and personal preference.

```
    switch (dataFilter) {
      case 'all':
        outputArr = beersArr;
        break;
      case 'imports':
        outputArr = filterByLocale('import');
        break;
      case 'ale':
        outputArr = [].concat(filterByLocale('ipa')).concat(filterByLocale('ale'));
        break;
      case 'random':
        outputArr = randomElement(beersArr);
        break;
      default:
        outputArr = filterByLocale(dataFilter);
        break;
    }
```